# Force V-Leaflet LMap to return the Bounds

Tags: java, leaflet, vaadin7, bounds

I'm using v-leaflet a vaadin portlet of leaflet.
I need the "Bounds" to create a WMS query.
The problem is that the method "getBound" returns null if I don't move tha map.
If I move the map there is a MoveEnd Listener that returns the Bounds values.

Is there a way to force the UI to return the Bounds ? Or a way to fire the event ?

Or is there a way to manually calculate the Bounds ?

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way, and I think the only way, to get the bounds is to set them when you create the map.

```
 Point p2 = new Point(45.13900627477143, 10.0579833984375);
 Point p = new Point(46.4790684581251, 7.16583251953125);
 Bounds bbox = new Bounds(p, p2);
 leafletMap.zoomToExtent(bbox);
```

And obviously you have to refresh the values with a MoveEndListener.